# How long should a WIndows Vista disk shrink take?

Tags: partitioning

Sorry if I'm asking this in the wrong place, but I recently found an old Inspiron 530 with Windows Vista Home Premium (In my Attic). I want to install Ubuntu and use it as a Minecraft Server. I read that I needed to create a disk partition, so I decided to shrink the C: drive by 82700 Megabytes. I still want the data on it. It's been over 12 hours (I started at about 4:00 Central Time on July 27th). I am wondering:

1. Is this normal?
2. Should I do something?
3. If so, how do I cancel the shrink?

Thanks in advance, I'll let y'all know if it finishes.

**EDIT:**

Well, I decided to try `Ctrl + Alt + Delete` after some time, and the screen went black. I pressed the `power` button on the computer, and the "Are you sure you want to shut down?" notice appeared. I clicked `cancel`, to find Windows Management Console open. I clicked the red `X`, and restarted the computer. Nothing blew up, vanished, or got destroyed. I would *not* recommend doing this. However, if anyone knows how long it should take, or if there's a safer way of canceling the shrink, I'd love to know.

Comment: This is one of those situations where your patience should be directly proportionate to the length of time since your last backup.

Comment: Since you said you found the computer, do you still want the data that's on it? If you want to install Ubuntu, do you intend to dual boot Vista and Ubuntu? If the answer to both is no, I would format the drive completely and start installing Ubuntu. You can [partition the drive during installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation).

Comment: @Worthwelle Yes, I do want the data. I should probably mention that I found the computer in my Attic

Comment: @Tetsujin Last backup = 10+ years ago

Comment: Then I'd give it a week & see what happens ;) If you shut it off, you'll likely kill it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yikes...that's a lot of time. Can you backup the memory while it's shrinking?

Comment: I wouldn't temp fate. Leave it to see if it completes. You should have backed it up before you started.

Comment: @Tetsujin I backed up the most important stuff (14,000 photos), but I'd prefer it all intact. I have a 500GB HDD, with 300GB free in C: drive.

Comment: @Tetsujin When I try to run any apps, it tells me it can't due to it not having necessary resources. Does this mean it's nearly finished?

Comment: tbh, I don't know, but it would definitely be wisest to leave it alone until it has.

Comment: I ignored wisdom. Nothing bad happened. Fairy tales have lied to me.